# Is it safe to use remote desktop to connect Windows 8 Professional from remote location?

Tags: windows, windows-8, security, remote-desktop

I want to access my home PC from outside from time to time.

Is it safe to enable port RDP forward on a home router and remote desktop home Windows 8 from a remote location?

Is another layer of SSH or VPN necessary?

Basically I don't want the traffic, especially the authentication information, to be eavesdropped by a third party. Assume the remote PC is safe.

Comment: How would you rdp into a Windows 8 home machine?

Comment: Ask Microsoft, is remote desktop software safe to use!!!

Comment: The question of trust is hard to answer...can you really trust either endpoint? Should your home machine trust a connection from a device which clearly promiscuously touches others, and should you allow your remote device to trust a home machine(s) which most likely has no restrictions and many users.

Answer (score 1):

Is it *necessary*? No. Is it safer? Yes. You can set up a VPN easily, so there really isn't any reason to add the extra layer of security. Follow these [directions](http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/) to create a VPN server on Windows.